# Raspberry Pi 4B Booting problem

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-4, boot-issues, bootloader

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B 2 GB model. I am running MQTT server on my Pi for an energy monitoring system in which around 16 ESP devices are connected to Pi. Besides EMS, Its also connected to Siemen S7-300 via MPI-USB Adapter to monitor some data on Node-red. It has been working fine since one month but suddenly now it isn't booting up. When I turn ON the power, Only the Red LED turns ON not the green one. I tried to recover the EEPROM using another SD Card but when I plugged it in it doesn't help either. I even format SD Card and install Raspbian Image full version again but issue is still the same. I don't know what to do. Is there anyone who can guide me?

**Update** with info from a comment:
I have tried all the list solutions at [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) but still acting LED isn't turning ON. Not even when I plugged spare SD Card to recover EEPROM.

Comment: Have a look at [[The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Comment: @Ingo I have tried all the list solutions there but still acting LED isn't turning ON. Not even when I plugged spare SD Card to recover EEPROM.